# Additional reason for closing a question

Tags: discussion

Can we get "insufficient information provided" added as a reason for closing a question?

Its a little like "too broad" but shows that the asker has not provided enough info, whereas too broad means there are simply too many answers.

Comment: We often use "unclear what you are asking" in that scenario. Did you have something specific in mind that isn't covered by that?

Comment: Specifically this appears in the "identify my bike" questions, where more information is needed, often in the form of photos.  Its quite clear that the question is "whats teh name of my bike's maker" but without further info there are too many answers.

Comment: This would clearly show that OP has to provide more info to move closer to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel like this already covers "insufficient information" pretty well:

> ### unclear what you're asking
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's
>   currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See
>   the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: In the ID my bike questions, it is quite clear what they're asking.  There is a lack of information provided, in order to answer the question.  So the onus is on the asker to provide more info via an edit or comment.  You're right this is the most suitable answer, but it doesn't clearly highlight the need for OP to do something further.